# Checking if an variable contains selected characters

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm new to JavaScript and I'm a little stuck trying to get this code to work. I'm stuck with the last part where I check the array to see if it contains those selected characters and if it does alert true and if not alert false.

```
var userinput = prompt('Input characters:');

var lowercase = userinput.toLowerCase();

alert(lowercase);

var allowedcharacters = [a,b,c,d,e,f];

if (lowercase){
  alert(true)
}
else{
  alert(false)    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check that your input just contains these characters you can do this using a regex.
This could be done like the following:

```
if (lowercase.match(/[abcdef]*/) == lowercase) {
 //Just contains allowed Characters
}
else {
 //contains forbidden characters
}
```

And in case you want to search if there is any allowed character you would do it like this:

```
if (lowercase.search(/.*[abcdef].*/) != -1) {
 //Contains at least one allowed character
}
else {
 //contains none of them
}
```

**EDIT**

This works fine if you know you'll always be using `[abcdef]`, but would suddenly break if you change `allowedcharacters` to be `["u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]`.  To make it more generic, build the regular expression differently.  For the first one, you would do:

```
if (lowercase.match(RegExp("[" + allowedcharacters.join("") + "]*")) == lowercase) {
    // ...
```

And the second one would be similar:

```
if (lowercase.search(RegExp(".*[" + allowedcharacters.join("") + "].*")) != -1) {
    // ...
```

In this way, your allowedcharacters can be anything, since `join`ing the array as indicated will put all the variables together without any spaces or commas.

**EDIT**
Here you find a running example: http://jsfiddle.net/Florian_Loch/YR8pw/

Comment: I'd call this perfect if you built a regex around `allowedcharacters.join("")` instead of hard coding it to [abcdef].

Comment: If I added .join what would this do? Would it look like this then? allowedcharacters.join("a,b,c,d,e,f")

Comment: @user2962494 I took the liberty of updating Florian's answer, so you could see what I was talking about.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Was just doing the example on jsfiddle... we did the same simultaniously ;)

Comment: @FlorianLoch Your fiddle is awesome.  Sorry if I jumped in too early; I hope I didn't offend by doing so.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein No, you didn't offend me - your suggestion of doing it more generic was just great! Thanks for that!

Comment: thats great thanks for this, if I wanted to now not alert out the results of it contains those characters and put in a return is this possible?

Comment: I answered your second thread - does this answer your question? ;)